# Same ad displayed 3 times in one "screen"

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, advertising

Just came to stackoverflow.com (without being logged in) and saw this:

[image: ads]
<sub>(source: [doheth.co.uk](http://www.doheth.co.uk/files/so-ads.jpg))</sub>

I'm assuming it's a bug since you wouldn't normally intend to show the same ad three times in such close proximity. It looks very garish to see a site plastered with logos like that.

Comment: Aren't you excited about the VS2010 release??

Comment: This is why I use AdBlock.... and gain rep.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, serious answer.

1. Remember that we only do a *reasonable amount* of non-animated, on-topic advertising. We expect unregistered / anonymous users to see a modicum of advertising to help support the site.
2. Earn 200 reputation and we suppress the leaderboard ads. You have 200 reputation, so why are you visiting while not logged in?
3. It is rare for all 3 ads to randomly cycle to the same exact ad, but it can happen.

Comment: On the plus side, repeating the same ad tends to get attention =P

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I don't mind ads at all, especially SO's responsible advertising. AdBlock is turned off for SO (any many others besides). I'm not complaining about the fact SO has ads, the ad content itself or even the number of ads. I just happened to visit while not logged in (since I was using a different browser), assumed it was a bug and thought you might like to know. Displaying the same advert 3 times looks bad IMO and it may put some people off the site. Perhaps there is a way to avoid this situation in future?

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly common practice in advertising called "roadblocking". It happens on the radio, on TV, and (as you can see) on the web.

The idea isn't to display the *exact* same banner (although, that will happen, from time to time), but to display three almost identical ads. Same colors, same theme, same message, etc. There are a lot of reasons why someone would want to do a roadblock, but they're mostly irrelavent to this discussion.

To expand on [Jeff's Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47312/same-ad-displayed-3-times-in-one-screen/47339#47339), we have *only* three ad zones. If you feel that's too many... then fine, whatever, but doing a roadblock is no more "garish" (as you put it) than not doing one. It's three ads, they're not animated, and they're relevant.

Comment: I'm just happy to see some of the vs2010 ad dollars go your way. I remember something previously about you guys not expecting to get any of that.

Comment: @Joel, thanks. I think you're referring to the last paragraph here (http://joelonsoftware.com/items/2009/12/13.html). It's not that we were/weren't expecting it; it's just that, because we operate so differently than the "ad agency world", it's a tremendous uphill battle.