# Microsoft advertising on SO?

Tags: discussion, advertising, microsoft

I just noticed this ad on SO.  I thought Microsoft had some bias against advertising on SO.

[Microsoft Web Camp http://ads.stackoverflow.com/ads/webCampsBanner220x250.png](http://ads.stackoverflow.com/a.aspx?Task=Click&ZoneID=4&CampaignID=886&AdvertiserID=205&BannerID=1537&SiteID=1)

Comment: Why would Microsoft have this bias?

Comment: @ccornet: keep in mind your link is not Microsoft actually doing the advertising, it's QBS. Not that I'm saying the original question is correct about the alleged bias, just that your link doesn't add argument against it.

Comment: @dbo I'm hoping a lot :D

Answer (score 7):

Microsoft seems to consider StackOverflow to be a VERY GOOD THING, because it helps their users and developers find answers without costing them anything.  One of the ways they show this is by counting SO participation when giving out MVP awards.

In fact, MSDN searches are now even returning Stack Overflow results.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-us?query=mantissa

I think that's awesome.  Sometimes imitation is the sincerest form of flattery, but sometimes just acknowledging someone else does it better is an even stronger form of praise.

Comment: +1 for microsoft, this is a good thing for msdn search and SO.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the likely source for your thoughts:
http://joelonsoftware.com/items/2009/12/13.html

Read down near the end where he quotes their "ad guy", Alex Papadimoulis.  Then read Alex' response to my comment on his answer here for clarification:
[Same ad displayed 3 times in one "screen"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47312/same-ad-displayed-3-times-in-one-screen/47495#47495)

Comment: Thanks Joel, that's what I was thinking about.  Obviously their marketer changed their mind or they got a different marketer.